# Excel - User confirmation on entered value and populate other field based on response

Tags: vba, excel, popup

I'm surprised I couldn't find a solution for what I perceived as a common question.

I'm entering a text value in a cell. If the user entry matches a specific value, I need a popup with yes/no question. If the user presses yes, I need to populate another call. If the user presses no, do nothing.

I understand we can use vbyesno in macro to achieve this but for some reason I'm not getting it right. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This small worksheet event macro monitors entries to cell **B9**.  If the user enters *shipping*, a popup asks if shipping costs should be entered.  If the user answers *yes*, the macro puts *100* in cell **C9**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address(0, 0) = "B9" Then
        If Range("B9").Value = "shipping" Then
            answer = Application.InputBox(prompt:="shipping costs required?", Type:=2)
            If answer = "yes" Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                    Range("C9").Value = 100
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This is only a demo that you can adapt to your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much. Though I needed MsgBox instead of InputBox where in I populated predefined values in some other cells based the entry into this cell. I've also applied the change in entire column. But your answer was the starting point for me to get it right. Thanks again!